# How Can I get data from an SQL Table with JavaServlet and Output it into a JSP-File trough a JavaBean?

Tags: java, jsp, javabeans

Well the question says everything i guess. The Idea is that i get the ID and read everyting from that row. (After that i want to jump to id 2 and do the same but first i have to figure out how)  Here are some Snippets i wrote so i can Upload it here:
[Here is my SQL Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfTma.png)

This is my Servlet:

```
@WebServlet("/TestServlet")
```

public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {

```
@Resource(lookup = "java:jboss/datasources/MySqlThidbDS")
private DataSource ds;
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private String fName;
private String lName;
private String adress;

public TestServlet() {

}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    request.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");

    TestBean tb = new TestBean();
    tb.setfName(gefName(fName));

    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    session.setAttribute("personData", tb);

    RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("testJSP.jsp");
    rd.forward(request, response);

}

public String gefName(String x) throws ServletException {

    try (Connection con = ds.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM person")) {
        pstmt.setString(1, x);

        try (ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery()) {

            if (rs != null && rs.next()) {

                fName = (rs.getString("first_name"));

            }

        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {

        throw new ServletException(ex.getMessage());
    }
    return x;
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    doGet(request, response);
}
```

}

This is my JSP

```
<p>First Name: ${personData.fName}</p>
<p>Last Name: </p>
<p>Adress: </p>
```

So my problem is that I cant get the name to show in my JSP file. I looked trough my scripts that our prof gave us but it gets confusing.

Comment: check and see in servlet what does `fName` have in it ?